# how to fix '-1' value displaying while clicked on navigator in highchart ? (When date-range not used for navigator)

Tags: reactjs, highcharts

I am trying to build a stacked bar chart with navigator using highchart which do not have a date range in x-Axis. 
Navigator is working fine when clicked or dragged. When clicked on left of navigator graph shows -1 value.  Does anyone have any idea?

```
I tried below logic : https://codepen.io/yugshah0106/pen/OeWpQq
```

Comment: @yug where are you exactly clicking can you add a screenshot?

Comment: Try clicking on left of extreme left on navigator. you will see -1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue occurs because you're using navigator with Highcharts instead of Highstock. When you swap a `Highcharts.chart` constructor with `Highcharts.stockChart` then the navigator will be created properly.

Note, that to have categories as you did before, in Highstock the `xAxis.labels.formatter` callback has to be used and return proper values:

```
  xAxis: {
    labels: {
      formatter: function(value) {
        return Vlans[this.value];
      }
    },
    tickInterval: 1
  }
```

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/p8o1ytw7/2/

Comment: Sorry for the late reply...  Using stockchart gives time range and date picker. So I used chart. 
 xAxis.labels.formatter worked for me.  Thank you.